# ETH stuck in Polygon (Matic): Bridge smart contract

Tags: nft, opensea, polygon-bridge

I was trying to make an NFT purchase on OpenSea and somehow I managed to send ETH to a "Polygon (Matic): Bridge" smart contract but didn't get the NFT I was expecting in exchange. Now I don't know how to get it back.

The NFT was listed in ETH but it was telling me to switch to the Polygon network when I was trying to buy it. But I didn't manage to transfer the ETH to the Polygon network because it was just sending me back to the Ethereum network (Metamask pop-up) when I was trying to do it on the interface in OpenSea. So I ended up making an offer (in ETH) for the NFT hoping that it would work out (instead of "buy Now"), gave the amount corresponding to the Buy price, and my Metamask pop up came up asking me to sign the transaction, which I did. But nothing happened, and after checking Etherscan I see that my ETH has been sent to a smart contract "Polygon (Matic): Bridge".

Does anyone know about this issue and what can be done to retrieve the ETH ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is it possible to share the transaction that sent the funds to the bridge contract? I'm not sure it will be possible to help without being able to see what happened.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem resolved itself... thankfully.

I came back a couple of hours later on OpenSea and saw that I had an "ETH on Polygon" balance corresponding to the amount I had sent. I was then able to proceed with the transaction.

So if the same happens to you, try coming back a couple of hours later...

Comment: You can also check if you have Wrapped ETH token on your Polygon wallet (e.g. on Metamask), by adding the following token address: 0x7ceB23fD6bC0adD59E62ac25578270cFf1b9f619